# React, Redux Saga using Typescript hitting 1 API Point to get paginated and non paginated data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I am totally stuck trying to hit the API to provide me with paginated data for VIew and none Paginated data for exporting as CSV

Redux Saga looks like this :

```
function* exportsearchPaymentRequests({
  payload,
  type
}: {
  payload: any;
  type: string;
}) {
  
  try {
    const { resBody }: any = yield paymentRequests.searchPaymentRequest(
      payload.searchData
    );
      console.log('hello saga')
      yield put ({ type: EXPORT_PAYMENT_REQUESTS, payload: resBody.payload });


  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

actions

```
export function getexportedPaymentRequests(searchData: any) {
  Object.keys(searchData).forEach(element => {
    if (searchData[element] === "") { delete searchData[element] }
  });
  console.log(searchData)

  return { type: GET_EXPORT_PAYMENT_REQUESTS, payload: {  searchData } };
}
```

reducer

```
function exportpaymentRequests(
  state: {} = {},
  action: { type: string; payload?: any }
) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case EXPORT_PAYMENT_REQUESTS:   
    return{
      ...state,
      exportedData: action?.payload?.data||[],
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

the on click consoles from the actions the correct data request...

BE Easy on me this isn't even my code I just got handed the job!

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a call instead of the direct function call

```
const { resBody }: any = yield call(paymentRequests.searchPaymentRequest,
      payload.searchData)
```